LLM: Train a specific GPT to match items in a list
I have a large dataset which contains only 2 columns:

car_name (a string)
Id (int)

The car_name is loosely normalized (e.g. "AUDI Q8 Sportback e-tron quattro") but not always (meaning we could have something like "C63 AMG").
I now receive car names over my API. I would like to match the names to the correct row in my dataset so that I easily search all cars of a specific type (using the ID).
The received names are expected to be riddled with typos and come in a variety of declination. The following would all need to match to my "C63 AMG" row:

MB C63amg
mercdes amg c63
c 63 amg benz mercedes
mercedez-benz amg c63 speedshift

I'm currently using TFIDF (to narrow down the search to the top 5 candidates), followed by levenshtein, which is slow but gives me a higher match rate. Regardless I am very unhappy with the results as, depending on the search term, the final match rate can be anywhere between 98% and 45% accurate.
I believe an LLM could help out here, provided it knows the initial list, it should be able to easily understand the problem above (which relies heavily on semantic understanding rather than straightforward math). Question now is how would I construct a training set for this?
Side note: The dataset has about 200'000 rows which is why I can't simply add it to the initial prompt.
